# Simple FTP transfer and edit script?

Tags: php, ftp

I'm looking for a PHP script I can install that will allow the basics of an FTP client:

- Connect to any FTP server
- List files & directories, navigate up and down directories
- File upload/download
- Create new files
- Delete/Rename/CHMOD files
- Edit and save back to server

Is there something out there besides Net2FTP?

Comment: Isn't FileZilla a desktop application? I'm looking for essentially that, but something I can install on my server

Comment: @JodyHeavener: Why do you need to do this from within your server?

Comment: I know it sounds silly, but I have to do a lot of work from my iPhone. I'm tired of fumbling through desktop browser-native clients, and I can't find an iPhone app client that works for me. My goal is to get a script, install it on my server, and rebrand/style it to work exactly for my needs. Just need it for my testing server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to take a look on following libraries:

1) https://github.com/suin/php-ftp-client

2) http://sourceforge.net/projects/radnetwork/

3) http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1743-PHP-FTP-client-in-pure-PHP.html

4) https://code.google.com/p/ftp-php/

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at the [FTP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ftp.php) and rig one up for yourself.